# What is the term for a particle spin's uncollapsed position? What is the orbiting "thing"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

I'm not sure if I have the correct visual model, but I imagine that a particle spin can be represented by a single point on the orbit, or by a superposition state (like a random plane through a corner of the sphere)

I'm curious what the name of a collapsed, known position is, and what that "thing" is called? I know that "thing" can be composed or thought of as the sum of two other "things" on the sphere (eigenvalues??), but I don't know what it's called by itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Spin is an intrinsic property independent of position, so a "spin's uncollapsed position" is a meaningless question. Are you confused on what _spin_ is?

Comment: @HantingZhang https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvCbrFD7wdU&t=12m50s what is the point on that diagram

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be called the Qbit or Qubit

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvCbrFD7wdU&t=12m50s

https://youtu.be/F_Riqjdh2oM?t=1042